# animate css animations speed control

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I am working on `animate.css` and i want to increase animation speed But there is delay time speed can be increase but after some delay but i don't want delay here are three parameters first is for delay other two's purpose ? `-webkit-transform: translate3d(3000%, 0, 0)`

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {   0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(3000%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(3000%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;   }   30% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(3000%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(3000%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }   100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);   } }

@keyframes slideInRight {   0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;   }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(3000%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(3000%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }   100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);   } }

.slideInRight {   -webkit-animation-name: slideInRight;   animation-name: slideInRight; }
```

here is my code of css which i am using 
Experts Please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

3 Parameters are translate3d(x,y,z)

Comment: thanks for reply please tell  me how can i increase animation speed without delay i want to make it fast as much as i can

Answer (score 0):

Hey basically you want to speed up your animation right?

To speed up css3 animation you should decrease the animation duration if you want to slow down your animation you should increase the animation duration.

Animation delay is a different it is used to delay the animation starts.

Example:

```
#yourElement {
-vendor-animation-duration: 3s; /*This is the animation duration */
-vendor-animation-delay: 2s;
-vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

[See This](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md)

Thank You.

Comment: Hey #chamath thank for your reply. yeah you are right i want to speed up my animations 
i did that but it is not working :( can you explain this

Comment: ok. can you try this, 

.yourElement{
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInRight ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   animation-name: slideInRight ;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-moz-animation-duration: 3s;
animation-duration: 3s;
}

So what is your browser? Pls use above and let me know

Comment: Thanks for help it's working now actually i am working with phonegape application so this will implement in  safari so now speed has been increased thank you very very much thumbs up for you :)

Comment: yeah this was my first app so facing some hurdles from now i will use ionic ...:)